# display records after spicific id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here the SQL query and I need some adjustment to it

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ic.img_path, ic.id
                    FROM images_community ic
                    WHERE ic.delete_flag = 0 AND ic.status = 1
                    ORDER BY ( SELECT (count(id = ic.id ) +  ic.views) 
                    FROM image_comments WHERE img_id = ic.id) DESC
```

I need to show record after specific ID

not limit and offset for sure  I need display rows after this id =5
this images retrieve

```
> images  id | img_path
>         1  | dafad.sjdbh
>         2  | dafad.sjdbh
>         5  | dafad.sjdbh
>         3  | dafad.sjdbh
```

IS there a way to display records after id = 5 in the same query retrieved

Comment: what do u mean by specific id.Give an example if possible

Comment: Did my answer work for you or not?

Comment: I found something similar get in which row this ID and start the limit from it
thnx Any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the row position for this ID and start the Limit from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use limit and offset to achieve it, please see [Limit, Offset](http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/queries-limit.html)

If you want all rows after offset just do

```
SELECT DISTINCT ic.img_path, ic.id
                    FROM images_community ic
                    WHERE ic.delete_flag = 0 AND ic.status = 1
                    ORDER BY ( SELECT (count(id = ic.id ) +  ic.views) 
                    FROM image_comments WHERE img_id = ic.id) DESC LIMIT (SELECT cout(*) FROM table_name) OFFSET my_row_offset
```

Comment: not limit for sure  I need display rows after this id 
this images retrieve 
images  id | img_path
        1  | dafad.sjdbh
        2  | dafad.sjdbh
        5  | dafad.sjdbh
        3  | dafad.sjdbh

show result after id = 5 and go on

Comment: just use the count of the table as the limit to show all rows after the offset. Like in the updated answer.